# Is squeezed state quantum?

Tags: quantum-optics

The wigner function of squeezed state has no negative values. And as far as I know a nagative value is an indecator of quantum effects. 
So does that mean a squeezed state is a classical light?

Comment: Positivity of WF is not a necessary and stufficient condition for classicality; the counterexample is exactly squeezed states.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero then what is it that is quantum about squeezed states?

Comment: @jgerber  one of the variances will be below the standard quantum limit.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero classically there is no limit to how small the Quadra tire variances can become so there must be a longer story to explain what non classical phenomena arise with squeezed states

Comment: @jgerber I don't follow.  There is a well-defined standard quantum limit, obtained from coherent states which are themselves "classical".  If you beat this SQL with a state, this state is quantum.  Of course you can only do this because the state contains quantum correlations.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I agree that coherent states are the most classical quantum states but they still have more noise than a true classical state would (zero noise). But, I also agree that squeezed states have reduced variance due to some sort of quantum correlations. I think the answer to this question has to do with quantifying those correlations, explaining a measurement that could measure them, and explaining why no classical theory could explain those correlations.